# How can i count the "count" or iteration or Calls of a method when comparing iterative and recursive methods.?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, iteration

I am suppose to write a program which calculate the number in a sequence. And Count the number of times it has been called.
I don't know how to go about switching between methods either for when the ietrative/recursive radio button is selected. Can i just use an if statement in the main?
I comment out some old mistakes, so just ignore the comments

The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type Abstract Button is not applicable for the arguments (Sequence)LINE33

Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens.LINE17-Im pretty sure i need this for the actionlistener

Type mismatch: cannot convert from JTextField to double.LINE 46

Syntax error on token "double", @ expected- line 49

```
     package sequence;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Sequence extends JFrame implements ActionsListener{
private static final double function=0;
private JTextField number=new JTextField(20),result=new JTextField(20),efficiency=new JTextField(20);
private static JRadioButton iterative= new JRadioButton("Iterative");JRadioButton recursive= new JRadioButton("Recursive");
private JButton compute = new JButton("Compute");


public Sequence(){
super (“Function Efficiency”);
setSize(350,250);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));
//add(new JLabel("Iterative Method"));add(form1);
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(iterative);
group.add(recursive);

//add(new JLabel("Recursive Method"));add(form2);
add(new JLabel("Enter N"));add(number);
add(new JLabel(""));add(compute);
add(new JLabel("Result: "));add(result);
add(new JLabel("Efficiency :"));add(efficiency);
efficiency.setEditable(false);
compute.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
result.setText(result.getText());
efficiency.setText(number.getText());
//double efficiency=0;
}
private   double  iterativemethod (){number.getText();
if  (iterative.isSelected()) {
for(double i=1;i<=0;i++)
{
double result=Double.parseDouble(number.getText())*2+Double.parseDouble(number.getText());
}
return result;
}

private static  double  recursivemethod (){
    double number1=number.getText();
if (number1<=1)
return number1;
return recursivemethod(number-1);
}

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sequence frame = new Sequence();
frame.setVisible(true);
if  (iterative.isSelected()) {

}
}

}
```

Comment: Fix the various syntax errors and post again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to parse the string value into double
- The recusion method require a missing argument of type double

Code

```
private static  double  recursivemethod (double number){ // Add argument
    double number1=Double.pareseDouble(number.getText()); // Parse Double
    if (number1<=1)
       return number1;
    return recursivemethod(number-1);
}
```

Comment: Adding an argument is all right, but I'd never post such lines as these under my by-line...